# Responsive circle based on it's content

Tags: css, responsive-design, geometry, css-shapes

I have this example [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Igaojsfiddle/bgut7411/) contains a circle, but I'm having trouble to make it **responsive according to it's content**, in the above example when the content is long, it overflows the circle.

```
.cd-single-point {
    margin:50px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.cd-single-point > a {
  position: relative;
  text-align:center;
  padding:2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background: #d95353;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.cd-single-point::after {
  /* this is used to create the pulse animation */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-animation: cd-pulse 2s infinite;
  -moz-animation: cd-pulse 2s infinite;
  animation: cd-pulse 2s infinite;
}
```

How can I achieve this **only with css**?

Comment: The elegant solution isn't responsive according to it's content : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/tf79qoqp/3/

Comment: Did you find a solution to your issue? Did my answer help?

Comment: Thanks @web-tiki, but see this: http://jsfiddle.net/Igaojsfiddle/70bznc75/1/. Even using min-height, we still have the same result. We can not leave the circle around tam so small... and try resize your browser. See my update on elegant solution. Hugs!

Comment: @lgao it is because you should be using `min-width` instead of `min-height` to keep a minimum size of the circle : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/70bznc75/3/ . The elegant solution still doesn't adapt it's size to the content.

Comment: Thanks @web-tiki, and had already applied it. What I mean is that the circle is not responsive. And really elegant solution is not responsive to the content, but for my case I will not need more than three characters within the circle, but I need his size suits. I removed the possible solution!

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [padding technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/css-a-way-to-maintain-aspect-ratio-when-resizing-a-div) on a pseudo element to keep the aspect ratio of the circle and make it responsive according to it's content :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/53bpm70g/)**

*HTML :*

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="in">+46546546</div>
</div>
```

*CSS :*

```
.wrap{
    color: #fff;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
.in{
    padding:60% 10%;
    margin-top:-0.6em;
}
.in:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:0;
    width:120%;
    padding-bottom:120%;
    background-color:#D95353;
    border-radius:50%;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but are you sure? http://jsfiddle.net/Igaojsfiddle/53bpm70g/1/

Comment: @lgao well the circle gets bigger when you add content, centering the content is an other question, give me a minute, I'll look for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

How about this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/bgut7411/9/

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="cd-single-point"> <a class="cd-img-replace" href="#">
            <div class="takeNumber">+99</div>
        </a>

        </div>
    </li>
    <!-- .cd-single-point -->
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
/* -------------------------------- 

Primary style

-------------------------------- */
 html * {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
body {
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family:"Roboto", sans-serif;
    color: #33435a;
    background-color: #3c4f6a;
}
.cd-single-point {
    margin:50px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.cd-single-point > a {
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;
    min-width: 20px;
    min-height: 20px;
    border-radius: inherit;
    background: #d95353;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s;
    transition: background-color 0.2s;
}
.cd-single-point::after {
    /* this is used to create the pulse animation */
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-radius: inherit;
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-animation: cd-pulse 2s infinite;
    -moz-animation: cd-pulse 2s infinite;
    animation: cd-pulse 2s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes cd-pulse {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px rgba(217, 83, 83, 0.8);
    }
    50% {
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px rgba(217, 83, 83, 0.8);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.6);
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px rgba(217, 83, 83, 0);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes cd-pulse {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px rgba(217, 83, 83, 0.8);
    }
    50% {
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px rgba(217, 83, 83, 0.8);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: scale(1.6);
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px rgba(217, 83, 83, 0);
    }
}
@keyframes cd-pulse {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
        -ms-transform: scale(1);
        -o-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px rgba(217, 83, 83, 0.8);
    }
    50% {
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px rgba(217, 83, 83, 0.8);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.6);
        -moz-transform: scale(1.6);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.6);
        -o-transform: scale(1.6);
        transform: scale(1.6);
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px rgba(217, 83, 83, 0);
    }
}
.takeNumber {
    color:white;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:12px;
    padding-top:3px;
}
```

**JS**

```
var numItems = $(".cd-single-point").length;
var myHeight, myWidth;
for (i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
    myWidth = $(".cd-single-point>a:eq(" + i + ")").width();
    myHeight = $(".cd-single-point>a:eq(" + i + ")").height();
    if (myWidth > myHeight) {
        $(".cd-single-point>a:eq(" + i + ")").css({
            height: myWidth + "px"
        });
    }
    if (myWidth < myHeight) {
        $(".cd-single-point:eq(" + i + ")>a").css({
            width: myHeight + "px"
        });
    }
    $(".takeNumber:eq(" + i + ")").css({
        "line-height": myWidth - parseInt($(".cd-single-point>a:eq(" + i + ")").css("padding"), 10) + "px"
    });
}
```

Comment: This is an answer very complete and very interesting. You thought of everything, including the alignment of the text! Thanks for your reply, even if made with .js

Answer (score 0):

If you're not opposed to some javascript you could check the width of the contents and then set an equivalent height.

```
$(function(){
   var elementWidth = $(".takeNumber").width();
    $(".cd-img-replace").css("height", elementWidth);
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jth2013/bgut7411/8/)**

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it works, but uses .js. Looks like we have a solution with CSS only our friend @web-tiki.

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/bgut7411/11/)**

css

```
.cd-single-point {
    height: 30px;
    min-width: 30px;
    width: auto;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    margin:50px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.cd-single-point > a {
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    min-width: 30px;
    width: auto;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 2;
    border-radius: inherit;
    background: #d95353;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s;
    transition: background-color 0.2s;
}
.takeNumber {
    color:white;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:12px;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
```

Comment: it does not look like a circle is not it? But anyway thanks for your reply.

Comment: I assumed that you need a circular label behind the numbers, beacause why will you want to increase the circle radius depending upon its content? I mean it doesn't required in design. Anyways Thanks for appreciation..:)